# c# Cannot call abstract generic method from static base class method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class with a static method which I want to call an abstract generic method but can't work out how to do this.

This is a different question to the one asked before, I cannot access the TryGetFallback abstract method from a static method on the base class.

The code I have so far is below.

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    public BaseClass(long id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : BaseClass where T : BaseClass, new() {
    protected BaseClass(long id)
        : base(id) {

    }

    public static T Get(long id) {
        T item;
        return TryGet(id, out item) ? item : default(T);
    }

    public static bool TryGet(long id, out T item) {
        item = null; // Try to get item from cache here
        if (item != null) { return true; }
        else {
            // Item not in cache so call TryGetFallback to attempt to retrieve it
            // Call TryGetFallback function
            // item = TryGetFallback(id);
            return item != null;
        }
    }

    protected abstract T TryGetFallback(long id);
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass> {

    public DerivedClass() : base(0) {

    }

    protected override DerivedClass TryGetFallback(long id) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I've tried to instantiate T as a new property and call TryGetFallback from that but the method isn't available.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it a compile time or runtime error?

Comment: You can't call an instance method from a static method.

Comment: You can't call an instance method from a static method, unless you instantiate a class in the method itself.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Or use a reference you get from somewhere else, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes or that ;-)

Comment: I've tried instantiating T as a class and calling the method from there but it's not compiling.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is not the same question as previously asked. I am having trouble calling the TryGetFallback method from a static method on the base class. The previous question was regarding inheritance.

Comment: @NeilT It looks like you're having trouble with the same issue that your other question is discussing - i.e. trying to get a missing instance by calling an instance method (this time, from a static context, but it does not change anything). The answer is the same, you cannot do it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've just managed to solve this problem and posted my solution on the previous question.